# Are $\{\}$ and $\{\{\}\}$ equal in set theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

According to set theory, are $\{\}$ and $\{\{\}\}$ equal?

Comment: NO; the first one is empty while the second one has one element: the empty set.

Comment: $P(A)="\{\}\in A"$ is true for one and false for the other. Therefore $\forall x(x\in\{\}\leftrightarrow x\in\{\{\}\})$ cannot be true.

Comment: We have $\{\}=\emptyset$, and $\{\{\}\}=\{\emptyset\}$.

Comment: A bag with an empty bag in it is able to be distinguished with an empty bag.

Comment: @JMoravitz I'll have to use that one!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. We have that $\{\}$ is the empty set, whereas $\{\{\}\}$ is the set which contains one element: the empty set. So $\{\{\}\}$ is not empty.

Answer (score 2):

No, in fact one definition of the natural numbers has $\{\}$ as 0, $\{\{\}\}=\{0\}$ as 1, $\{\{\},\{\{\}\}\}=\{0,1\}$ as 2, etc.